# why `boost::filesystem::exists` return false when a file does exist?

Tags: c++, boost

```
        const boost::filesystem::path fileName( "/tmp/hello.log" );
        if ( boost::filesystem::exists( fileName ) )
        {
            // do sth
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "file doesn't exist: " << std::endl;
        }
```

Here is the issue I have:

Before I can process the log file(i.e. /tmp/hello.log), I need to check whether or not the file is completed. If the file is not complete, I will check the file later.

To run simulation, I choose the following methods:

Case I:

The log file first is incomplete(i.e. without END as the last line)

```
$echo "END" >> /tmp/hello.log
```

My application runs as expected. In other word, my application will try again if the file is incomplete and later successfully process the completed log file.

Case II:

The log file first is incomplete(i.e. without END as the last line)
I use `vi` to manually insert one line in the end while the application at the same time keeps checking the following lines:

```
        const boost::filesystem::path fileName( "/tmp/hello.log" );
        if ( boost::filesystem::exists( fileName ) )
        {
            // do sth
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "file doesn't exist: " << std::endl;
        }
```

After I append the last line to the file, my application will report error and say "file doesn't exist". But in fact, the log file is there.

Why in Case II, the boost function will return false while in Case I the function return true.

Comment: First of all, when you edit the file in VI, you *do* open the `/tmp/hello.log` file? Not just e.g. `vi hello.log` in some other path? Secondly, the code you show doesn't check if the file is "incomplete" or not, just if it exists. Even an "incomplete" file exists.

Comment: I'd guess vi creates a backup copy, i.e. first `hello.log` is renamed to `hello.log~` (or similar), then `hello.log` is written with the new content. Between those two events, your program will not find the file.

Comment: 1> I manually open the /tmp/hello.log with `vi /tmp/hello.log` 2> I didn't show the code for checking complete because I only check the complete after I find the file does exist.

Comment: In my system, vi will generate a temporary file as /tmp/.hello.log.swp. However, the /tmp/hello.log is still there

Comment: @q0987:  When you type ":x" (or ":w") into vi, it will write the changes to hello.log.swp, and then rename hello.log.swp to hello.log.  If you try to detect whether the file exists at that point, filesystem::exists may return false.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I have tried to use `vi -n /tmp/hello.log` and I still see the same thing.

Comment: this boost bug might be related https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13084

Answer (score 3):

> why `boost::filesystem::exists` return false when a file does exist?

It won't. The file does *not* exist.

You say that this works unless you perform the editing in *vi*. Bear in mind that *vi* is not a simple command-line tool, but a powerful text editor. It may very well be using a temporary file (say, `/tmp/hello.log~`) for modifications. Until you save changes, those changes won't be found at `/tmp/hello.log`. You should study *vi*'s documentation for more information on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your program does not have sufficient privileges to stat the file, or that the request to stat it has failed for other reasons.

From boost's documentation, note that the `exists()` function's return value depends on whether or not the stat operation returned an error.

> bool exists(file_status s) noexcept
>
> Returns: status_known(s) && s.type() != file_not_found
>
> bool status_known(file_status s) noexcept
>
> Returns: s.type() != status_error

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#exists