# std::filesystem::exists() returns false although the file does exist

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

```cpp
const std::string propName(pPropName, len);
std::filesystem::path p(pPropName);
if (!std::filesystem::exists(p)) {
    LOG(    Log::Level::ERROR,
            "File %s does not exist w/len = %u",
            propName.c_str(),
            len);
    return;
}
```

For some reason, it happened a few times in a roll that `std::filesystem::exists(p)` returned `false` (after I modified that existing file and saved with `vi`) while the file did exist -- I immediately `ls`-ed on that file.

There is [a very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278280/) reporting a similar issue in `boost::filesystem::exists()`.

One answer there suggested that `vi` create a temporary file before the file is saved (i.e. `:w`).  However, the above code was manually triggered a few seconds after I hit `:wq!` in `vi`.  I even tried 2 more times after 1 minute and 2 minutes.  `std::filesystem::exists()` still returned `false`.

Another answer suggested that it could be a permission issue.  However, it isn't the case for me because after 11 minutes, the same code and same binary saw the file (i.e. `std::filesystem::exists()` returned `true`) and I didn't even restart my process (that contains the code above).

The tough part is that it is not 100% reproducible -- I just edited the code above to pass in an instance of `std::error_code` to try to get the error code.  But I can't reproduce it now.

Any idea?

I used `g++` 8.3.1 to compile and the code was running on CentOS 7.7.

=====

Update #1: The file size is about 5190 bytes and it lives on an SSD on a 3+GHz Intel server.

Update #2:  Here is the `strace`'s output (captured when `std::filesystem::exists(p)` returned true):

```
stat("/server/my_file.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=5077, ...}) = 0
open("/server/my_file.ini", O_RDONLY) = 15
```

Update #3:  Found the issue -- `pPropName` might not be null-terminated sometimes (should have used `propName`).  And `std::error_code.message().c_str()` returned "Success", strange.  Anyway, thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that's what's happening (and it'd be very unusual): If the file is unlinked by `vi` (as a last resort) before writing it down - this could happen. Let's say you have full permissions to remove files in the directory, but not to update the actual file. Removing the file and writing a new file would work.
Otherwise, `vi` would most probably write to a temporary file and _move_ it into place so `exists(p)` would always succeed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for sharing your thought.  The strange thing is that even after 2 mins I hit `:wq!` in `vi`, the code above still couldn't see the file although `ls` saw it.  2 mins to move the file is quite a long time especially the file is only 5190 bytes on a SSD.

Comment: Can you `strace` the process to see the underlying (failing) system call?

Comment: @Botje I was trying to do so while trying to reproduce outside business hours (as during business hours, I am not allowed to cause any instability....`strace` usually slows things down at millisecond level, which isn't acceptable in my business case).

Comment: I think I had some weird behaviors like this under gcc-8 if compiled without explicitly linking to stdc++fs (i.e: `--std=c++17 -lstdc++fs`) ... I completely forgot the why and how

Comment: @Fluffy I did compile with `--std=c++17 -lstdc++fs`.  Those 2 are mandatory in order to use `std::filesystem`.  Otherwise, it won't compile.  If you think of something, let me know :)

Comment: Run your app with `strace` and see what filename it passes to `stat`.

Comment: Is the file on a network drive, like nfs or smb?

Comment: @TedLyngmo according to `lsblk -f`, the file lives on `xfs`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin please see "update #2".  thanks.

Comment: @HCSF You need `strace` output that demonstrates the problem, not the lack of it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin sure.  will try again once it happens.  At the moment, I couldn't reproduce it yet.  Tho, I checked my log on prod, it happened few times in the past few weeks.  So I wasn't dreaming.  lol.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is `vi` that actually renames the target file before creating a new file (which surprised me).

I verified it by running this program while editing a file (`the_file`).

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path p("the_file");
    while(std::filesystem::exists(p));
    std::cout << "gone\n";
}
```

When doing `:wq` in `vi` the program prints `gone` and exits.

Also, the `strace` of the `vi` session verifies it. This is the `strace -ff` log after hitting return giving the command `:wq`. Note the `rename`, `openat` sequence:

```
read(0, "\r", 250)                      = 1
select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "\r", 1)                       = 1
stat("/home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
access("/home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/the_file", W_OK) = 0
write(1, "\33[?25l\33[?2004l\33[>4;m", 20) = 20
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "\"the_file\"", 10)            = 10
stat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
access("the_file", W_OK)                = 0
getxattr("the_file", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fffb80a2f50, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
stat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
lstat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
lstat("4913", 0x7fffb80a32e0)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "4913", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW, 0100644) = 3
fchown(3, 1000, 100)                    = 0
stat("4913", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
unlink("4913")                          = 0
stat("the_file~", 0x7fffb80a3000)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
stat("the_file~", 0x7fffb80a1fd0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("the_file~")                     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

```
rename("the_file", "the_file~")         = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "the_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = 3
```

```
ftruncate(3, 0)                         = 0
write(3, "hejsan\n", 7)                 = 7
fsync(3)                                = 0
stat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
stat("the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
fchmod(3, 0100644)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
setxattr("the_file", "system.posix_acl_access", "\2\0\0\0\1\0\6\0\377\377\377\377\4\0\4\0\377\377\377\377 \0\4\0\377\377\377\377", 28, 0) = 0
write(1, " 1L, 7C written", 15)         = 15
stat("/home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/the_file", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7, ...}) = 0
unlink("the_file~")                     = 0
write(1, "\r\r\n\33[?2004l\33[?1l\33>", 18) = 18
write(1, "\33[?25h\33[>4;m\33[?1049l\33[23;0;0t", 29) = 29
close(4)                                = 0
unlink("/home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/.the_file.swp") = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

A simpler way to verify this is to check the `inode` number of the file before and after you've used `vi`. Opening a file and doing `:wq` will create a new file, with a new `inode` number.

This does not explain why the file isn't visible after a long time though. That could perhaps be because of some caches somewhere. Apparently the XFS file system has (or had) some issues with its caches not being updated properly for small files. Perhaps you could add this if `exists(p) == false`:

```
system("sync;sync;sync"); // old classic tripple sync
```

to synchronize cached writes to persistent storage. After that, try checking it again.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for checking `vi`'s behavior with detailed analysis.   If xfs cached and so didn't flush the buffer back to the disk immediately, I wonder how `ls` saw the file and how `vi` saw the cached content (as I did `vi` again and I saw my modification there).

Comment: Yes, the part about XFS is a long shot, but it's still worth trying `sync` to see if it has any effect.